# How to intercept call

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I need to use a progress bar or loader indicator and start that when I'm trying to query to Azure.
Is this possible and how to do it. example of the query for now as you see I'm doing manualy:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('site', 'key');
var dataTable = client.getTable('table');
function GetAzureData(){
progress.start();
dataTable.take(12).where({condition:condition}).read().done(
                    function (d) {
//fill data
                       progress.completed();
                    }, function (err) {
                        progress.completed();
                    });
}
```

But because I have a lot of methods like this I need to intercept this when I call "where" or "read" ect and show progress (loader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *filter* to a client object, and that would be applied to all requests going from the client. Unfortunately there's not a lot of documentation on this feature, but you can see a little bit of it on [this doc](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#customizing) or in the [documentation for the `MobileServiceClient.withFilter` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554202.aspx).

For your scenario, the implementation would be somewhat similar to this one:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('site', 'key');
var clientWhichTracksProgress = client.withFilter(function(request, next, callback) {
    progress.start();
    next(request, function(error, response) {
        progress.completed();
        callback(error, response);
    });
});
var dataTable = clientWhichTracksProgress.getTable('table');
```

And the rest of the code would be the same (without the calls to the progress tracker).

Updated: I wrote a blog post which goes into more details on service filters for JavaScript at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2014/02/24/using-service-filters-with-the-mobile-services-javascript-sdk.aspx.